# Cannot compile sources in Xcode 6 above beta 5

Tags: ios, compilation, swift, xcode6

I was writing the update to my app since Xcode beta 2 has been released. I used beta 3, 4 and 5 also. Since beta 6 has been released I cannot compile my sources. I was thinking that this is because some errors in beta 6 but it is not. In Xcode 6 GM is the same situation. Here is an error I cannot understand. Could you help me in understanding what's wrong in here?

> CompileSwiftSources normal x86_64 com.apple.xcode.tools.swift.compiler
>       cd /Users/tomkowz/Workspace/private/iWrapper-Swift/iWrapper
>       export PATH="/Applications/Xcode6GM.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode6GM.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
>       /Applications/Xcode6GM.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swiftc
>   -target x86_64-apple-ios7.0 -module-name iWrapper -Onone -sdk /Applications/Xcode6GM.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.0.sdk
>   -g -module-cache-path /Users/tomkowz_priv/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache -I
>   /Users/tomkowz_priv/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iWrapper-fmyxporfmphnayfgvkiwdrbrbino/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator
>   -F /Users/tomkowz_priv/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iWrapper-fmyxporfmphnayfgvkiwdrbrbino/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator
>   -c -j4 /Users/tomkowz/Workspace/private/iWrapper-Swift/iWrapper/iWrapper/TSAssetsLibrary/TSAssetPredicate.swift
>   /Users/tomkowz/Workspace/private/iWrapper-Swift/iWrapper/iWrapper/OptionButton.swift
>   /Users/tomkowz/Workspace/private/iWrapper-Swift/iWrapper/iWrapper/TSAssetsLibrary/TSAssetsGroup.swift
>   /Users/tomkowz/Workspace/private/iWrapper-Swift/iWrapper/iWrapper/IWRSettings.swift
>   /Users/tomkowz/Workspace/private/iWrapper-Swift/iWrapper/iWrapper/IWRDeviceInfo.swift
>   /Users/tomkowz/Workspace/private/iWrapper-Swift/iWrapper/iWrapper/TSSlideViewController.swift
>   /Users/tomkowz/Workspace/private/iWrapper-Swift/iWrapper/iWrapper/Product.swift
>   /Users/tomkowz/Workspace/private/iWrapper-Swift/iWrapper/iWrapper/IWRDrawing.swift
>   /Users/tomkowz/Workspace/private/iWrapper-Swift/iWrapper/iWrapper/TutorialViewController.swift
>   /Users/tomkowz/Workspace/private/iWrapper-Swift/iWrapper/iWrapper/FrameSettingsViewController.swift
>   /Users/tomkowz/Workspace/private/iWrapper-Swift/iWrapper/iWrapper/IWRPopoverController.swift
>   /Users/tomkowz/Workspace/private/iWrapper-Swift/iWrapper/iWrapper/PreviewViewController.swift
>   /Users/tomkowz/Workspace/private/iWrapper-Swift/iWrapper/iWrapper/ProductStore.swift
>   /Users/tomkowz/Workspace/private/iWrapper-Swift/iWrapper/iWrapper/IWRFamily.swift
>   /Users/tomkowz/Workspace/private/iWrapper-Swift/iWrapper/iWrapper/ScreenshotsViewController.swift
>   /Users/tomkowz/Workspace/private/iWrapper-Swift/iWrapper/iWrapper/TSPurchaseKit/TSPurchaseManager.swift
>   /Users/tomkowz/Workspace/private/iWrapper-Swift/iWrapper/iWrapper/ShopViewController.swift
>   /Users/tomkowz/Workspace/private/iWrapper-Swift/iWrapper/iWrapper/IWRPosition.swift
>   /Users/tomkowz/Workspace/private/iWrapper-Swift/iWrapper/iWrapper/ColorOptionsCell.swift
>   /Users/tomkowz/Workspace/private/iWrapper-Swift/iWrapper/iWrapper/AlbumsViewController.swift
>   /Users/tomkowz/Workspace/private/iWrapper-Swift/iWrapper/iWrapper/ColorOptionButton.swift
>   /Users/tomkowz/Workspace/private/iWrapper-Swift/iWrapper/iWrapper/AlbumCell.swift
>   /Users/tomkowz/Workspace/private/iWrapper-Swift/iWrapper/iWrapper/IWRTranslucentView.swift
>   /Users/tomkowz/Workspace/private/iWrapper-Swift/iWrapper/iWrapper/NoResultsCell.swift
>   /Users/tomkowz/Workspace/private/iWrapper-Swift/iWrapper/iWrapper/IWRScreenSize.swift
>   /Users/tomkowz/Workspace/private/iWrapper-Swift/iWrapper/iWrapper/OptionsCell.swift
>   /Users/tomkowz/Workspace/private/iWrapper-Swift/iWrapper/iWrapper/AssetsCollectionViewLayout.swift
>   /Users/tomkowz/Workspace/private/iWrapper-Swift/iWrapper/iWrapper/CenteredButtonCell.swift
>   /Users/tomkowz/Workspace/private/iWrapper-Swift/iWrapper/iWrapper/TSPurchaseKit/TSProductsManager.swift
>   /Users/tomkowz/Workspace/private/iWrapper-Swift/iWrapper/iWrapper/IWRLoadingIndicator.swift
>   /Users/tomkowz/Workspace/private/iWrapper-Swift/iWrapper/iWrapper/IWRAnalytics.swift
>   /Users/tomkowz/Workspace/private/iWrapper-Swift/iWrapper/iWrapper/LoadingCell.swift
>   /Users/tomkowz/Workspace/private/iWrapper-Swift/iWrapper/iWrapper/IWRType.swift
>   /Users/tomkowz/Workspace/private/iWrapper-Swift/iWrapper/iWrapper/KeychainUtility.swift
>   /Users/tomkowz/Workspace/private/iWrapper-Swift/iWrapper/iWrapper/TSAssetsLibrary/TSAsset.swift
>   /Users/tomkowz/Workspace/private/iWrapper-Swift/iWrapper/iWrapper/DrawingInfo.swift
>   /Users/tomkowz/Workspace/private/iWrapper-Swift/iWrapper/iWrapper/MainPhoneViewController.swift
>   /Users/tomkowz/Workspace/private/iWrapper-Swift/iWrapper/iWrapper/TSAssetsLibrary/TSAssetsLibrary.swift
>   /Users/tomkowz/Workspace/private/iWrapper-Swift/iWrapper/iWrapper/IWRTranslucentCircleButton.swift
>   /Users/tomkowz/Workspace/private/iWrapper-Swift/iWrapper/iWrapper/IWRTranslucentButton.swift
>   /Users/tomkowz/Workspace/private/iWrapper-Swift/iWrapper/iWrapper/AssetCell.swift
>   /Users/tomkowz/Workspace/private/iWrapper-Swift/iWrapper/iWrapper/MenuViewController.swift
>   /Users/tomkowz/Workspace/private/iWrapper-Swift/iWrapper/iWrapper/IWRCustomColors.swift
>   /Users/tomkowz/Workspace/private/iWrapper-Swift/iWrapper/iWrapper/TranslucentCell.swift
>   /Users/tomkowz/Workspace/private/iWrapper-Swift/iWrapper/iWrapper/AppDelegate.swift
>   /Users/tomkowz/Workspace/private/iWrapper-Swift/iWrapper/iWrapper/IWRProtocols.swift
>   /Users/tomkowz/Workspace/private/iWrapper-Swift/iWrapper/External/ILTranslucentView/Source/ILTranslucentView.swift
>   /Users/tomkowz/Workspace/private/iWrapper-Swift/iWrapper/iWrapper/IWROrientation.swift
>   /Users/tomkowz/Workspace/private/iWrapper-Swift/iWrapper/iWrapper/AssetsCollectionView.swift
>   /Users/tomkowz/Workspace/private/iWrapper-Swift/iWrapper/iWrapper/MainPadViewController.swift
>   /Users/tomkowz/Workspace/private/iWrapper-Swift/iWrapper/iWrapper/OtherOptionsViewController.swift
>   /Users/tomkowz/Workspace/private/iWrapper-Swift/iWrapper/iWrapper/OptionToSelect.swift
>   /Users/tomkowz/Workspace/private/iWrapper-Swift/iWrapper/iWrapper/IWRStatistics.swift
>   /Users/tomkowz/Workspace/private/iWrapper-Swift/iWrapper/iWrapper/IWRColor.swift
>   /Users/tomkowz/Workspace/private/iWrapper-Swift/iWrapper/iWrapper/ShopCell.swift
>   /Users/tomkowz/Workspace/private/iWrapper-Swift/iWrapper/iWrapper/PreviewCell.swift
>   /Users/tomkowz/Workspace/private/iWrapper-Swift/iWrapper/iWrapper/IWRLocalizedString.swift
>   /Users/tomkowz/Workspace/private/iWrapper-Swift/iWrapper/iWrapper/IWRContext.swift
>   -output-file-map /Users/tomkowz_priv/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iWrapper-fmyxporfmphnayfgvkiwdrbrbino/Build/Intermediates/iWrapper.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/iWrapper.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/iWrapper-OutputFileMap.json
>   -parseable-output -serialize-diagnostics -emit-dependencies -emit-module -emit-module-path /Users/tomkowz_priv/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iWrapper-fmyxporfmphnayfgvkiwdrbrbino/Build/Intermediates/iWrapper.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/iWrapper.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/iWrapper.swiftmodule
>   -Xcc -I/Users/tomkowz_priv/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iWrapper-fmyxporfmphnayfgvkiwdrbrbino/Build/Intermediates/iWrapper.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/iWrapper.build/swift-overrides.hmap
>   -Xcc -iquote -Xcc /Users/tomkowz_priv/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iWrapper-fmyxporfmphnayfgvkiwdrbrbino/Build/Intermediates/iWrapper.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/iWrapper.build/iWrapper-generated-files.hmap
>   -Xcc -I/Users/tomkowz_priv/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iWrapper-fmyxporfmphnayfgvkiwdrbrbino/Build/Intermediates/iWrapper.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/iWrapper.build/iWrapper-own-target-headers.hmap
>   -Xcc -I/Users/tomkowz_priv/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iWrapper-fmyxporfmphnayfgvkiwdrbrbino/Build/Intermediates/iWrapper.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/iWrapper.build/iWrapper-all-target-headers.hmap
>   -Xcc -iquote -Xcc /Users/tomkowz_priv/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iWrapper-fmyxporfmphnayfgvkiwdrbrbino/Build/Intermediates/iWrapper.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/iWrapper.build/iWrapper-project-headers.hmap
>   -Xcc -I/Users/tomkowz_priv/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iWrapper-fmyxporfmphnayfgvkiwdrbrbino/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/include
>   -Xcc -I/Users/tomkowz/Workspace/private/iWrapper-Swift/iWrapper/Pods/Headers
>   -Xcc -I/Users/tomkowz/Workspace/private/iWrapper-Swift/iWrapper/Pods/Headers/AFNetworking
>   -Xcc -I/Users/tomkowz/Workspace/private/iWrapper-Swift/iWrapper/Pods/Headers/ISO8601DateFormatterValueTransformer
>   -Xcc -I/Users/tomkowz/Workspace/private/iWrapper-Swift/iWrapper/Pods/Headers/RKValueTransformers
>   -Xcc -I/Users/tomkowz/Workspace/private/iWrapper-Swift/iWrapper/Pods/Headers/RestKit
>   -Xcc -I/Users/tomkowz/Workspace/private/iWrapper-Swift/iWrapper/Pods/Headers/RestKit/CoreData
>   -Xcc -I/Users/tomkowz/Workspace/private/iWrapper-Swift/iWrapper/Pods/Headers/RestKit/Network
>   -Xcc -I/Users/tomkowz/Workspace/private/iWrapper-Swift/iWrapper/Pods/Headers/RestKit/ObjectMapping
>   -Xcc -I/Users/tomkowz/Workspace/private/iWrapper-Swift/iWrapper/Pods/Headers/RestKit/Support
>   -Xcc -I/Users/tomkowz/Workspace/private/iWrapper-Swift/iWrapper/Pods/Headers/SOCKit
>   -Xcc -I/Users/tomkowz/Workspace/private/iWrapper-Swift/iWrapper/Pods/Headers/TransitionKit
>   -Xcc -I/Users/tomkowz/Workspace/private/iWrapper-Swift/iWrapper/Pods/Headers/Vendor/LibComponentLogging/Core
>   -Xcc -I/Users/tomkowz/Workspace/private/iWrapper-Swift/iWrapper/Pods/Headers/Vendor/LibComponentLogging/NSLog
>   -Xcc -I/Users/tomkowz_priv/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iWrapper-fmyxporfmphnayfgvkiwdrbrbino/Build/Intermediates/iWrapper.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/iWrapper.build/DerivedSources/x86_64
>   -Xcc -I/Users/tomkowz_priv/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iWrapper-fmyxporfmphnayfgvkiwdrbrbino/Build/Intermediates/iWrapper.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/iWrapper.build/DerivedSources
>   -Xcc -DDEBUG=1 -Xcc -DCOCOAPODS=1 -emit-objc-header -emit-objc-header-path /Users/tomkowz_priv/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iWrapper-fmyxporfmphnayfgvkiwdrbrbino/Build/Intermediates/iWrapper.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/iWrapper.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/iWrapper-Swift.h -import-objc-header /Users/tomkowz/Workspace/private/iWrapper-Swift/iWrapper/Bridging-Header.h
>
> Command
>   /Applications/Xcode6GM.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swiftc
>   failed with exit code 1

**Edit 1**

After removing CocoaPods and bridging header problem still occurs (compiled xcodeproj instead of workspace). Here is the log:

> CompileSwiftSources normal x86_64 com.apple.xcode.tools.swift.compiler
>       cd /Users/tomkowz/Workspace/private/iWrapper-Swift/iWrapper
>       export PATH="/Applications/Xcode6GM.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode6GM.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
>       /Applications/Xcode6GM.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swiftc
>   -target x86_64-apple-ios7.0 -module-name iWrapper -Onone -sdk /Applications/Xcode6GM.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.0.sdk
>   -g -module-cache-path /Users/tomkowz_priv/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache -I
>   /Users/tomkowz_priv/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iWrapper-aturdqvpimzhhledxpbuycyfbjxj/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator
>   -F /Users/tomkowz_priv/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iWrapper-aturdqvpimzhhledxpbuycyfbjxj/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator
>   -c -j4 /Users/tomkowz/Workspace/private/iWrapper-Swift/iWrapper/iWrapper/TSAssetsLibrary/TSAssetPredicate.swift
>   /Users/tomkowz/Workspace/private/iWrapper-Swift/iWrapper/iWrapper/OptionButton.swift
>   /Users/tomkowz/Workspace/private/iWrapper-Swift/iWrapper/iWrapper/TSAssetsLibrary/TSAssetsGroup.swift
>   /Users/tomkowz/Workspace/private/iWrapper-Swift/iWrapper/iWrapper/IWRSettings.swift
>   /Users/tomkowz/Workspace/private/iWrapper-Swift/iWrapper/iWrapper/IWRDeviceInfo.swift
>   /Users/tomkowz/Workspace/private/iWrapper-Swift/iWrapper/iWrapper/TSSlideViewController.swift
>   /Users/tomkowz/Workspace/private/iWrapper-Swift/iWrapper/iWrapper/Product.swift
>   /Users/tomkowz/Workspace/private/iWrapper-Swift/iWrapper/iWrapper/IWRDrawing.swift
>   /Users/tomkowz/Workspace/private/iWrapper-Swift/iWrapper/iWrapper/TutorialViewController.swift
>   /Users/tomkowz/Workspace/private/iWrapper-Swift/iWrapper/iWrapper/FrameSettingsViewController.swift
>   /Users/tomkowz/Workspace/private/iWrapper-Swift/iWrapper/iWrapper/IWRPopoverController.swift
>   /Users/tomkowz/Workspace/private/iWrapper-Swift/iWrapper/iWrapper/PreviewViewController.swift
>   /Users/tomkowz/Workspace/private/iWrapper-Swift/iWrapper/iWrapper/ProductStore.swift
>   /Users/tomkowz/Workspace/private/iWrapper-Swift/iWrapper/iWrapper/IWRFamily.swift
>   /Users/tomkowz/Workspace/private/iWrapper-Swift/iWrapper/iWrapper/ScreenshotsViewController.swift
>   /Users/tomkowz/Workspace/private/iWrapper-Swift/iWrapper/iWrapper/TSPurchaseKit/TSPurchaseManager.swift
>   /Users/tomkowz/Workspace/private/iWrapper-Swift/iWrapper/iWrapper/ShopViewController.swift
>   /Users/tomkowz/Workspace/private/iWrapper-Swift/iWrapper/iWrapper/IWRPosition.swift
>   /Users/tomkowz/Workspace/private/iWrapper-Swift/iWrapper/iWrapper/ColorOptionsCell.swift
>   /Users/tomkowz/Workspace/private/iWrapper-Swift/iWrapper/iWrapper/AlbumsViewController.swift
>   /Users/tomkowz/Workspace/private/iWrapper-Swift/iWrapper/iWrapper/ColorOptionButton.swift
>   /Users/tomkowz/Workspace/private/iWrapper-Swift/iWrapper/iWrapper/AlbumCell.swift
>   /Users/tomkowz/Workspace/private/iWrapper-Swift/iWrapper/iWrapper/IWRTranslucentView.swift
>   /Users/tomkowz/Workspace/private/iWrapper-Swift/iWrapper/iWrapper/NoResultsCell.swift
>   /Users/tomkowz/Workspace/private/iWrapper-Swift/iWrapper/iWrapper/IWRScreenSize.swift
>   /Users/tomkowz/Workspace/private/iWrapper-Swift/iWrapper/iWrapper/OptionsCell.swift
>   /Users/tomkowz/Workspace/private/iWrapper-Swift/iWrapper/iWrapper/AssetsCollectionViewLayout.swift
>   /Users/tomkowz/Workspace/private/iWrapper-Swift/iWrapper/iWrapper/CenteredButtonCell.swift
>   /Users/tomkowz/Workspace/private/iWrapper-Swift/iWrapper/iWrapper/TSPurchaseKit/TSProductsManager.swift
>   /Users/tomkowz/Workspace/private/iWrapper-Swift/iWrapper/iWrapper/IWRLoadingIndicator.swift
>   /Users/tomkowz/Workspace/private/iWrapper-Swift/iWrapper/iWrapper/IWRAnalytics.swift
>   /Users/tomkowz/Workspace/private/iWrapper-Swift/iWrapper/iWrapper/LoadingCell.swift
>   /Users/tomkowz/Workspace/private/iWrapper-Swift/iWrapper/iWrapper/IWRType.swift
>   /Users/tomkowz/Workspace/private/iWrapper-Swift/iWrapper/iWrapper/KeychainUtility.swift
>   /Users/tomkowz/Workspace/private/iWrapper-Swift/iWrapper/iWrapper/TSAssetsLibrary/TSAsset.swift
>   /Users/tomkowz/Workspace/private/iWrapper-Swift/iWrapper/iWrapper/DrawingInfo.swift
>   /Users/tomkowz/Workspace/private/iWrapper-Swift/iWrapper/iWrapper/MainPhoneViewController.swift
>   /Users/tomkowz/Workspace/private/iWrapper-Swift/iWrapper/iWrapper/TSAssetsLibrary/TSAssetsLibrary.swift
>   /Users/tomkowz/Workspace/private/iWrapper-Swift/iWrapper/iWrapper/IWRTranslucentCircleButton.swift
>   /Users/tomkowz/Workspace/private/iWrapper-Swift/iWrapper/iWrapper/IWRTranslucentButton.swift
>   /Users/tomkowz/Workspace/private/iWrapper-Swift/iWrapper/iWrapper/AssetCell.swift
>   /Users/tomkowz/Workspace/private/iWrapper-Swift/iWrapper/iWrapper/MenuViewController.swift
>   /Users/tomkowz/Workspace/private/iWrapper-Swift/iWrapper/iWrapper/IWRCustomColors.swift
>   /Users/tomkowz/Workspace/private/iWrapper-Swift/iWrapper/iWrapper/TranslucentCell.swift
>   /Users/tomkowz/Workspace/private/iWrapper-Swift/iWrapper/iWrapper/AppDelegate.swift
>   /Users/tomkowz/Workspace/private/iWrapper-Swift/iWrapper/iWrapper/IWRProtocols.swift
>   /Users/tomkowz/Workspace/private/iWrapper-Swift/iWrapper/External/ILTranslucentView/Source/ILTranslucentView.swift
>   /Users/tomkowz/Workspace/private/iWrapper-Swift/iWrapper/iWrapper/IWROrientation.swift
>   /Users/tomkowz/Workspace/private/iWrapper-Swift/iWrapper/iWrapper/AssetsCollectionView.swift
>   /Users/tomkowz/Workspace/private/iWrapper-Swift/iWrapper/iWrapper/MainPadViewController.swift
>   /Users/tomkowz/Workspace/private/iWrapper-Swift/iWrapper/iWrapper/OtherOptionsViewController.swift
>   /Users/tomkowz/Workspace/private/iWrapper-Swift/iWrapper/iWrapper/OptionToSelect.swift
>   /Users/tomkowz/Workspace/private/iWrapper-Swift/iWrapper/iWrapper/IWRStatistics.swift
>   /Users/tomkowz/Workspace/private/iWrapper-Swift/iWrapper/iWrapper/IWRColor.swift
>   /Users/tomkowz/Workspace/private/iWrapper-Swift/iWrapper/iWrapper/ShopCell.swift
>   /Users/tomkowz/Workspace/private/iWrapper-Swift/iWrapper/iWrapper/PreviewCell.swift
>   /Users/tomkowz/Workspace/private/iWrapper-Swift/iWrapper/iWrapper/IWRLocalizedString.swift
>   /Users/tomkowz/Workspace/private/iWrapper-Swift/iWrapper/iWrapper/IWRContext.swift
>   -output-file-map /Users/tomkowz_priv/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iWrapper-aturdqvpimzhhledxpbuycyfbjxj/Build/Intermediates/iWrapper.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/iWrapper.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/iWrapper-OutputFileMap.json
>   -parseable-output -serialize-diagnostics -emit-dependencies -emit-module -emit-module-path /Users/tomkowz_priv/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iWrapper-aturdqvpimzhhledxpbuycyfbjxj/Build/Intermediates/iWrapper.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/iWrapper.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/iWrapper.swiftmodule
>   -Xcc -I/Users/tomkowz_priv/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iWrapper-aturdqvpimzhhledxpbuycyfbjxj/Build/Intermediates/iWrapper.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/iWrapper.build/swift-overrides.hmap
>   -Xcc -iquote -Xcc /Users/tomkowz_priv/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iWrapper-aturdqvpimzhhledxpbuycyfbjxj/Build/Intermediates/iWrapper.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/iWrapper.build/iWrapper-generated-files.hmap
>   -Xcc -I/Users/tomkowz_priv/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iWrapper-aturdqvpimzhhledxpbuycyfbjxj/Build/Intermediates/iWrapper.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/iWrapper.build/iWrapper-own-target-headers.hmap
>   -Xcc -I/Users/tomkowz_priv/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iWrapper-aturdqvpimzhhledxpbuycyfbjxj/Build/Intermediates/iWrapper.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/iWrapper.build/iWrapper-all-target-headers.hmap
>   -Xcc -iquote -Xcc /Users/tomkowz_priv/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iWrapper-aturdqvpimzhhledxpbuycyfbjxj/Build/Intermediates/iWrapper.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/iWrapper.build/iWrapper-project-headers.hmap
>   -Xcc -I/Users/tomkowz_priv/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iWrapper-aturdqvpimzhhledxpbuycyfbjxj/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/include
>   -Xcc -I/Users/tomkowz_priv/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iWrapper-aturdqvpimzhhledxpbuycyfbjxj/Build/Intermediates/iWrapper.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/iWrapper.build/DerivedSources/x86_64
>   -Xcc -I/Users/tomkowz_priv/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iWrapper-aturdqvpimzhhledxpbuycyfbjxj/Build/Intermediates/iWrapper.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/iWrapper.build/DerivedSources
>   -Xcc -DDEBUG=1 -emit-objc-header -emit-objc-header-path /Users/tomkowz_priv/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iWrapper-aturdqvpimzhhledxpbuycyfbjxj/Build/Intermediates/iWrapper.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/iWrapper.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/iWrapper-Swift.h
>
> Command
>   /Applications/Xcode6GM.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swiftc
>   failed with exit code 1

Comment: Download the GM Xcode version and try again.

Comment: I did it. No changes. Also I removed bridging header and all connection to classes imported inside - still the same.

Comment: Did you try clearing your derived data folder?

Comment: Yes, many times, no changes.

Comment: I think that's is a code issue but compiler is unable to show this correctly. I removed all files except AppDelegate and it is compiling. I'll check it tomorrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I fixed it! As mentioned in comment under the question as suspected this is a a problem with code syntax which was changing through all betas. I don't know why Xcode was not pointing that here in line X is a wrong type (Implicitly unwrapped optional or optional instead of non-optional in overrided obj-c properties). The big step to fix this issue was to use `xcodebuild` tool. It logs everything so you can really see in which file the problem is. The next step was to read all the code and check functions declarations. After few changes all compile successfully.

Comment: It sounds like a compiler bug - it should give you an error instead of crashing the compiler.  These only get fixed if you can distill them to a nugget and then submit it.

Comment: I'll report it after I test it in separated environment.